# Are questions related to camera calibration on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm having a hard time getting answers for openCV based questions on SO. I understand that [programming related questions should be on SO](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105/are-opencv-questions-on-topic). However, I am also doing camera calibration and have some questions related to that. Given that some of those questions are not specifically about openCV but how to perform the calibration, I wonder if DSP is a better place to ask those questions and if they would be on-topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided you haven't asked the question on a different SE forum, feel free to ask it here. We have several OpenCV questions here.

Just try to ascertain whether it's really a programming question, rather than one related to image processing. Calibration questions (even using OpenCV) are on-topic; questions  about which function to use... perhaps not so much.